# General constructor for all JS types

Tags: javascript

If I am trying to declare a variable and I need to provide a default case because it won't let me create the key without a value, I thought I could make the same basic value for all empty variables, but it still be of the type I want it to be when I actually assign it the value.

```
var x = "";
var y = 0;
var z = null;
```

I know that JS is pretty good about knowing which type (except those crazy situations between strings and numbers), but would `null` be able to be over-written by all types, and then that variable would be of that type?

so if we had `var x = "";` then x is a String already.  Obviously if I did `var x = "something"` then it would still be a String, or if I did `var x = 12` then it would change the type and the value.

What is the type if it is assigned `null`?

So what is your suggestion for a placeholder value for a variable that just needs to be created?

Comment: It's not a dictionary, it's an object.

Comment: the type when something is assinged `null` is `object`.

Comment: keep in mind javascript is a dynamic language.

Comment: It sounds like the most JS-idomatic value here is `undefined`, assuming you want the property to exist (i.e., detected by the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), but otherwise not having a value). I'm not clear what you mean by "would `null` be able to be over-written by all types" -- you can overwrite anything with anything.

Comment: You don't need to declare it at all.

Comment: @SLaks   I'm using backbone, which requires me to have the value of the key defined in the model.

Comment: @chrisFrisina I think it would be much better for you to edit your question with your *actual problem* (including whatever you're doing in Backbone), to avoid running into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Let us help you solve your *actual problem*, not help you implement what you think might be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

null = Object;

undefined = no type specified

In Javascript, everything is an Object of some form or other, unless it has not been associated with any data, in which case it is `undefined`.

So you probably want something like:

```
var defaults = {
  beats: "",
  numberOfBeats: 0,
  representation: undefined
};
```

Then in your code you could query whether the `representation` index has any data in it by:

```
if(typeof defaults['representation'] === "undefined"){

    // representation has not yet been defined

}
```

Comment: `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"`. So `var a = {}; typeof a["b"] === "undefined"`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen if your point is that he doesn't need to index the Object at all, I'm not sure I agree, because he will probably want to use the object to iterate over some values as is common with default logic. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen in case you hadn't noticed, I have compared the `typeof` result with a `String`, not `undefined` alone.

Comment: My point is that the type of `undefined` is `"undefined"`, meaning that it has a type. My suggestion is to make a schema, this solves all OPs problems. `typeof` is not a function so those `()` do nothing. You should also use `===` since the return value of `typeof` is a string.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I see your point now. Have altered the answer. You are right about the schema too, but I get the feeling this is a pretty negligible piece of functionality within his code-base so I'm opting for the quickest way forward. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof null` is `"object"`

And it's a common mistake that novice js programmers make to assume that `undefined` and `null` are the same (they're not).

Answer (score 1):

```
var x;
x = 6;
typeof x // 'number'

x = '6';
typeof x // 'string'

x = null;
typeof x // 'object'

x = {};
typeof x // 'object'

x = 3;
typeof x // 'number'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `typeof` is not always enough. Ex: `typeof new Number(6); // "object"` `typeof []; // "object"`

Comment: No doubt, just pointing out that you can always keep reassigning x even after you made it null. :)

Answer (score 1):

A *default value* is not the same as *no value*. Sometimes it's important to be able to make that distinction.

Since you do need some way to detect if you have a value you can use a value that indicates that the value is undefined, like: `undefined`. This does mean that your *dictionary* is initially empty.

Depending on your data types you can also use `null`. Of course if `null` is a possible value you can't use it. If you have no safe undefined value you can have another property say something about the value, like `is value X set: yes/no` (this is one step in the direction of a schema / meta data).

---

A tip I can give you is that if you have data, with strongly typed data types, work on a schema language to describe the data. You will get the `undefined` value detection basically for free.